# Stopping setInterval and executing the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, if-statement, timeout, settimeout, setinterval

So if the condition of $('#purple-title').html() != "PLEASE SCAN YOUR CARD" is met, I'd like to exit the interval and do what is inside of that if() function.

My problem has been solved and the following code works just fine!

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
      });
      var refreshID = setInterval(function() {

        $('#purple-title').load('dbcheck.php');
        if ($('#purple-title').html() != "PLEASE SCAN YOUR CARD") {

          clearInterval(refreshID);

          $("#waiting-for-signal").animate({
            opacity: '0'
          }, 300);
          $("#purple-title").animate({
            opacity: '0'
          }, 300);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#waiting-for-signal").css("visibility", "hidden");
            $("#purple-title").html("Welcome!");
            $("#screen").prepend('<img id="checked" src="assets/check.gif"/>');
            $("#screen").prepend('<p id="purple-title" class="purple-title" style="margin:20px 0px 0px 0px;">WELCOME<br /><br /><strong>ALEN ŠIMUNIC</strong><br /><br />UID: 31.42.43.25</p>');
            $("#checked").css("opacity", "1");
          }, 300);
          $("#purple-title").animate({
            opacity: '1'
          }, 300);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#purple-title").animate({
              opacity: '0'
            }, 300);
            $("#checked").animate({
              opacity: '0'
            }, 300);
          }, 2200);
          setTimeout(function() {
            location.reload();
          }, 2500);
        }

      }, 500);
    });
```

Comment: `if ($('#purple-title').html() != "PLEASE SCAN YOUR CARD") { clearInterval(refreshID);`

Comment: This exits the interval before any of the script inside if() is executed

Comment: It just does not run the next interval

Comment: @AlenŠimunic thats not a problem... as youre already in *running code* you dont need to take care of that

Comment: Sorry, I was using it the wrong way, I will post the code that works now! Thanks all!

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clearInterval(refreshID);
```

Thats it...

Comment: Sorry, I was using it the wrong way, I will post the code that works now! Thanks all!